# triggering segue after an ibaction

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, segue, ibaction

I'm trying to perform a segue after my IBAction has already happend.
This is my code and as you can see when I press the button I make a get request with alamofire. The problem is that the request is (as I understand) an async method so the segue will unwind and perform eve if the getPlayer method hasn't done what it's supposed to. The only way I could fix it is by putting the perfomrsegue method inside an if statement where I check for the value of person.name, but I have to press the button twice and I just can't figure out how to solve this!

```
@IBAction func getPlayerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    userDefaults.set(tagTextField.text!, forKey: "userTag")
    let userTag = userDefaults.string(forKey: "userTag")
    getPlayerData(with: userTag!)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToPlayerProfile", sender: self)
 }
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destionationVC = segue.destination as! PlayerProfileViewController
    destionationVC.playerName = player.name
    print(destionationVC.playerName)
    print("prepared for segue")
}


func getPlayerData (with tag: String) {
    let finalURL = baseURL + tag
    Alamofire.request(finalURL, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            print("Got player data!")
            let playerJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            self.player.name = playerJSON["name"].stringValue
            print(self.player.name)
        } else {
            print("Error: \(response.result.error!)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should pass a closure to `getPlayerData` and then perform the segue in the closure that is called after the network operation is complete.  Remember to dispatch the segue on the main queue.  Probably even better is to perform the segue immediately and load the data in the next view controller; that way you can display a loading UI element to provide immediate feedback to the user .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform segue after async alamofire request is completed.

```
func getPlayerData (with tag: String) {
    let finalURL = baseURL + tag
    Alamofire.request(finalURL, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            print("Got player data!")
            let playerJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            self.player.name = playerJSON["name"].stringValue
            print(self.player.name)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToPlayerProfile", sender: self)
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: \(response.result.error!)")
        }
    }
}
```